# How to overlay multiple images onto certain original images using python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, file-handling

I am trying to create a program in which I should be able to overlay one image over another base image using python and opencv and store the output image in an other folder . I am using opencv to achieve this however the code I have written is not giving the desired result.

```
import cv2
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np

path_wf = 'wf_flare'
path_fr = 'captured_flare'

files_wf = [ f for f in listdir(path_wf) if isfile(join(path_wf,f))]
files_fr = [ fl for fl in listdir(path_fr) if isfile(join(path_fr,fl))]

img_wf = np.empty(len(files_wf), dtype = object)
img_fr = np.empty(len(files_fr), dtype = object)
img = np.empty(len(files_wf), dtype = object)
k = 0
for n in range(0, len(files_wf)):
    img_wf[n] = cv2.imread(join(path_wf, files_wf[n]))
    img_fr[k] = cv2.imread(join(path_fr, files_fr[k]))
    print("Done Reading"+str(n))
    img_wf[n] = cv2.resize(img_wf[n], (1024,1024),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    

    img[n] = 0.4*img_fr[k] + img_wf[n]

    fn = listdir(path_wf)
    name = 'C:\Flare\flare_img'+str(fn[n])
    print('Creating...'+ name + str(n+10991))
    cv2.imwrite(name,img[n])
    k += 1
    if(k%255 == 0):
        k = 0
    else:
        continue
```

the folder organization is pasted below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I want the output images to come here:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but don't use backslashes as path separators. You actually can if you use `r'c:\strings\like\this'`, but it is much easier to remember never to use backslashes. You don't need them. Even better, read up on using `Pathlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in the following line:

```
name = 'C:\Flare\flare_img'+str(fn[n])
```

1. In Python, special characters in strings are escaped with backslashes. Some examples are `\n` (newline), `\t` (tab), `\f` (form feed), etc.  In your case, the `\f` is a special character that leads to a malformed path. One way to fix this is to use raw strings by adding an `r` before the first quote:

```
'C:\Flare\flare_img'
Out[12]: 'C:\\Flare\x0clare_img'

r'C:\Flare\flare_img'
Out[13]: 'C:\\Flare\\flare_img'
```

2. Do not just concatenate strings when you create filesystem paths. Sooner or later you end up misplacing a path separator. In this case, it is missing because `fn[n]` does not start with one. Let's say that `fn[n] = "spam.png"`.  Then assuming you do

```
name = r'C:\Flare\flare_img'+str(fn[n])
```

your value for `name` will be

```
C:\\Flare\\flare_imgspam.png
```

which is not what you intended.

Use `os.path.join` or the modern `pathlib.Path` as previously suggested. It is also redundant to wrap `fn[n]` in the `str` function because `os.listdir` already returns a list of strings.

The changes you need to make are as follows:

```
# add to imports section
from pathlib import Path

# add before for-loop
out_path = Path(r'C:\Flare\flare_img')

# change inside for-loop
name = out_path / fn[n]
```

Documentation: Python [Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: aaaand backslashes have special meaning in normal strings

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Edited to explain both mistakes in OP's approach.

Comment: if it is not too much to ask, Could you please correct the line of code which you pointed out? Also , i am getting a broadcasting error ```img[n] = 0.4*img_fr[k] + img_wf[n]``` here.

Comment: The error message is ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (752,1008,3) (1024,1024,3)

Comment: Added complete `pathlib` syntax. Regarding the broadcasting error, it appears that your two input images are different sizes. I'm not sure how to appropriately adjust them for your problem domain. If they must stay at the original size, you need to perform the overlay operation at a deeper level (pixelwise).